# pydev with eclipse does create test database when running test

Tags: python, django, pydev

It is a django project. I am using pydev 2.6. How do I make it to use the Django test runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django test runner can be accessed by creating a new (Run or Debug) configuration for your project using the Django template. Set your main module as `manage.py` and under the Arguments tab enter "test" (or any other `manage.py` arguments you need).

Comment: You can fine-tune the tests you're running by supplying some arguments to your call to `manage.py`. For example, you can run the tests for one app or a list of them. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#test-app-or-test-identifier) for more information

Comment: that means I have to create 300 run config for 300 unit tests

Comment: I disagree. For example, you can run the tests for an app by supplying the app name as an argument to `manage.py test`, and you may supply as many app names as you wish. You're also able to create your own [test suites](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#grouping-tests) which group tests in units that make sense to you.